# disable write protection on stm32l4

Tags: embedded, stm32ldiscovery

Does anyone know how to disable write protection or check if user address is write protected?  I'm using stm32l4xx series and would like to do it by embedded code in program not by using STM32 ST-Link Utility.  Any examples are very appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: what part of the stm32 documentation did you not understand?

Comment: I don't know where is the addresses of write protection regions.  Also is the write protection regions by default enable or disable?

Comment: everything you need to know about in application programming of the flash is documented in the stm32 documentation.  likewise register access read only vs read write, etc.  sram is read/write.  whatever you can read or write (that has anything worth reading or writing).

Comment: There are many documents on ST website, this can be complicated when you don't know what you need. The information your are requesting is in the document named "reference manual". You should go on the page for your specific device because there are subfamilies in the L4 series.

Comment: @Julien I have found the manual, but due to language barrier I may get everything correctly as in the manual.  For what I understand is that the write protection by default is disable meaning that none of the FLASH area is write protected, am I correct?

Comment: Usually protections are disabled by default, yes this is correct.